# Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) + MS Word Document Template

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

My requirement is to create a word document dynamically i.e. create a document with template having data placeholders like version, author, header etc. How can I create this template & open the document and replace the placeholder with actual data by code (C#)? I have to put placeholders in document header/footer, document page & watermark.

Also, how can I pass data from other project to VSTO project?

Please suggest me some demo videos, user guide, tutorial or manual regarding the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create your template with fields or bookmarks to contain your data.

Using bookmarks you create your template and add bookmarks where you want to insert your data. In your VSTO addin would fill the bookmark with the following. This example is from an application level addin

For the sake of this I'll assume you are retrieving data from a data base and that you have a bookmark called ProductName

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
string productName = GetProductNameFromDatabase();
doc.Bookmarks["ProductName"].Range.Text = productName;
```

I am afraid this only answers the specific question of adding data to a word document.